# How to check Reset all subsites to inherit this alternate CSS URL Programitically?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, css

I had set Alternate CSS URL programmatically. But next CheckBox of "Reset all subsites to inherit this alternate CSS URL" is not checked it self. I want to check it programmatically.

Please Suggest how this can be done

Comment: nice question bro. :) +1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
currentWeb.Site.RootWeb.AlternateCssUrl = filePath
currentWeb.Site.RootWeb.Update();
```

This will apply in all Site & SubSites.